# How to customize Jacoco for Espresso tests in Android

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, android-espresso, jacoco

I have a library project with some weird configuration between modules. Due to some specific restrictions, I have now 3 module: **core** (main module), **core-test** (where my unit tests are) and a **core-app** (where my Espresso tests are).

At this time, I need to generate a coverage report to make it available on out CI server. Using properties such `additionalSourceDirs` and `additionalClassDirs`, I created a custom task for enabling the **core** classes to be shown in the resulting `jacoco.exec` file. But for the Espresso tests, I am not able to find a way to customize this, as the jacoco configuration node on Android Gradle plugin seems to have [no options for anything](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoOptions.html). Enabling `testCoverageEnabled` for a specific build configuration works, it generates the coverage, but only for the classes in **core-app** (I know, in a *regular* project, this is the expected behavior), so the `coverage.ec` file doesn't have the execution data for my other classes.

Anyone knows a way to add more classes / sources to the coverage task for integration tests? (maybe extending `AndroidJUnitRunner` in some way or changing the task itself through Groovy?)

Comment: Can you please post your build.gradle?

Comment: Hey, I'm basically in the exact same situation. I know this is old, but is there any chance you could share what you ended up doing to solve this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.5.201505241946"
}
```

Also in buildTypes:

```
debug {
    testCoverageEnabled = true
```

Run

```
gradle tasks
```

and you will see a task called (If you are using debug build for coverage)

```
createDebugCoverageReport
```

Run

```
gradle createDebugCoverageReport
```

You will see coverage.ec in the following folder

```
$build_dir/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/debug/coverage.ec
```

Which device you are using and which OS ? Some device with a particular OS produces empty coverage.ec Please share more information about OS and device you are using?